# Do files under res/xml get merged by gradle?

Tags: android, xml, gradle, android-resources

I have a file, `res/xml/analytics_tracker.xml` that stores my google analytics variables. I want to use different variables in my release vs debug builds.

So I have `main/xml/analytics_tracker.xml` (has maybe 6 xml-elements) & `release/xml/analytics_tracker.xml` (1 xml-element).

I decompiled my release apk via apktool and looked at the `analytics_tracker.xml` file. It only had the 1 element from the `release` xml file.

Shouldn't it merge the two xml files into one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally if you want to have different debug and release versions of files, you would have a debug version in separate debug/.... folder, and release version in main/.... folder, at least this is how it's always in my projects. If it can's find a separate folder for a build type, it takes main/... version.

In your case I guess it found a release/.... version of your analytics_tracker file and used only it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the [official doc](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-merging) about Resource Merging with gradle.

You can find the reason of your issue.

> The priority order is the following:
>
> BuildType -> Flavor -> main -> Dependencies.
>
> This means that if a resource is declared in both **the Build Type and in >main, the one from Build Type will be selected**.